# Auth error:TypeError: URL is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, dialogflow-es

I am getting this error while deploying in AWS:

> "Auth error:TypeError: URL is not a constructor" "DF ERROR:14
>   UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: URL is
>   not a constructor"

Although locally it is working fine.
Not getting any response after it calls to Dialogflow.

Comment: Please share the code, its difficult to understand what is the issue without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

My code is :

```js
// Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
        var dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
        var sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
                credentials: {
                    private_key: config.dialogflow.privateKey,
                    client_email: config.dialogflow.clientEmail
                }
            }
        );

        // Define session path
        var sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(config.dialogflow.projectId, req.sessionID);

        // The text query request.
        var request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {},
        };
        if (chatBotEvent.text.text){
            request.queryInput.text = {
                text:chatBotEvent.text.text,
                languageCode: chatBotEvent.text.languageCode
            };
        }
        if (chatBotEvent.event.name){
            var dialogflowService = new DialogflowService();
            request.queryInput.event = {
                name:chatBotEvent.event.name,
                parameters:dialogflowService.jsonToStructProto(chatBotEvent.event.parameters),//event.parameters,
                languageCode: chatBotEvent.event.languageCode,
            };
        }
        // Send request and log result
        return sessionClient
            .detectIntent(request)
            .then(function(responses){
                var incidentData = $this.analyseResponse(responses[0].queryResult);
                if (incidentData){
                    responses[0].queryResult.incident = incidentData;
                }
                return responses[0].queryResult;
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error('ERROR:', err);
            });
```